# Changing FontSize in Summernote very Buggy

Tags: javascript, font-size, summernote

I am having trouble using the fontsize feature of Summernote.  It seems to work best in Chrome- but even then I must type the text first, highlight it, then select the fontsize I want from the Summernote Text Editor to change it.  Other browsers don't seem to work at all.

I thought this might be caused by some class that's overwriting the font-size so I tried using the Developer Tool in IE to undo any suspect classes and then try changing the font again, but with no luck.  I have also searched all over the internet and found very little which leads me to believe it must be something wrong with my particular installation of Summernote.  Moreover, I can't seem to find a demo of Summernote anywhere online- which would be helpful in determining if this is just a 'me' issue or part of a much larger problem.

Any help is very much appreciated

```
<textarea class="loneTextArea" style="width: 400px; height: 60px;"></textarea>
```

How I instantiate Summernote:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.loneTextArea').summernote({
        toolbar: [
          ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
          ['font', ['strikethrough']],
          ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['height', ['height']],
          ['codeview', ['codeview']]
        ],
        height: 60,
        width: 400,
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('.loneTextArea').summernote({
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['font', ['strikethrough']],
      ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
      ['height', ['height']],
      ['codeview', ['codeview']]
    ],
    fontSizes: [ '12', '16', '18', '24'], //here set the font size options you want
    height: 60,
    width: 400,
 });

});
```

OR, try this:

```
$('.loneTextArea').summernote('fontSize', 20);
```